# JOIN two data frames in R based on timestamps that are maximum x minutes apart

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to JOIN two data frames in R on a Date column (measurements at different timestamps). The date timestamps are not equal at the two frames, so I need to round the timestamps is some way in order to be able to JOIN.
I thought of:

1. First round the values to the closest minute, then JOIN
   The problem with this approach is that the rounding can cause close measurements to be rounded to different minutes, so they can't be JOINed
2. JOIN a record based on the closest value from the second frame (using "roll" from "data.table")
   The problem with this approach is that measurements might be missing at each frame, so the second solution above won't work (the closest next measurement after the missing one is wrong to JOIN with). My question is how can I JOIN two record from two frame with the following condition:
   IF the difference between the timestamps is less than 2 minutes - JOIN them to 1 record
   ELSE (and in general) - keep all the the records that don't have a match with N/A values at the columns of the JOINed frame

** the two frames can be of different length due to missing measurements

Temperature Table

```
Name        Date                Value   Unit
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:02:08 14.6    degC
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:20:18 15.5    degC
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:38:29 14      degC
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:54:45 14.5    degC
Temperature 01/04/2017 01:14:44 13.9    degC`
```

Humidity Table

```
Name               Date                   Value   Unit
Relative Humidity   01/04/2017 00:02:25    56      %
Relative Humidity   01/04/2017 00:20:34    50      %
Relative Humidity   01/04/2017 00:38:44    59      %
Relative Humidity   01/04/2017 01:15:01    58      %`
```

result table

```
Name.x      Date                Value.x Unit.x name.y         value.y unit.y
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:02    14.6    degC   Relative Humidity  56      %
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:20    15.5    degC   Relative Humidity  50      %
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:38    14      degC   Relative Humidity  59      %
Temperature 01/04/2017 00:54    14.5    degC   NA                 NA      NA
Temperature 01/04/2017 01:14    13.9    degC   Relative Humidity  58      %`
```

Comment: What's the `class` of your `Date` columns? How are you currently rounding the values?

Comment: Date columns are `POSIXct type`, and currently the rounding function used is - `round_date {lubridate}`

Answer (score 0):

Rolling joins in the `data.table` package can do this for you. `roll = 120` sets it to a max difference of 120 seconds. `nomatch = NA` to get the missing value for no match.

```
library("data.table")
library("anytime")    # just to quickly get your strings as times

d1 = data.table(date = anytime(c("01/04/2017 00:02:08","01/04/2017 00:20:18","01/04/2017 00:38:29","01/04/2017 00:54:45","01/04/2017 01:14:44")),
    value = c(14.6, 15.5, 14  , 14.5, 13.9))
d2 = data.table(date = anytime(c("01/04/2017 00:02:25", "01/04/2017 00:20:34", "01/04/2017 00:38:44", "01/04/2017 01:14:40")),
    value = c(56, 50, 59, 58))

d2[, timestamp_d2 := timestamp]


d = d2[d1, on = 'date', roll = 'nearest', nomatch = NA]

d[abs(timestamp - timestamp_d2) <= 120]
```

Comment: This will work only if assuming that d2 measurements are always taken a few seconds after d1 measurements. I can not assume that. d2 measurements can be taken a few seconds before or a few seconds after d1 measerements

Comment: This could be done by setting `roll = 'nearest' to join to nearest observation and then subsetting on whether the absolute difference between the two timestamps is smaller than 120. I'll edit the answer as it takes a few steps.

Comment: In the current solution there won't be NA values in the result table and some observations will be lost