# How can I join two data frames in R based on timestamps that are a maximum of x minutes apart

Tags: r, dataframe

I aim to combine two dataframes into a unified dataframe using timestamps. Nonetheless, there exists a time discrepancy of a few minutes between the timestamps in the two dataframes. If rows match based on the provided date/time within the specified time difference range, I want to retrieve the corresponding values; otherwise, I would like to obtain missing values (NA).

I have tried this: [JOIN two data frames in R based on timestamps that are maximum x minutes apart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832044/join-two-data-frames-in-r-based-on-timestamps-that-are-maximum-x-minutes-apart)

However, it is still not working.

First DF:

```
            timstamp Temperature
1 2021-06-24 00:00:00        26.6
2 2021-06-24 00:15:00        26.3
3 2021-06-24 00:30:00        26.1
4 2021-06-24 00:45:00        25.3
5 2021-06-24 01:00:00        25.2
6 2021-06-24 01:15:00        25.2
```

Second DF:

```
                   DT     RH
1 2021-06-24 06:33:01 73.259
2 2021-06-24 06:48:01 66.982
3 2021-06-24 07:03:01 66.982
4 2021-06-24 07:18:01 66.982
5 2021-06-24 07:24:01 72.482
6 2021-06-24 07:33:01 66.982
```

---

Data samples:

```r
DF1 <- structure(list(timstamp = structure(c(1624507200, 1624508100, 1624509000, 1624509900, 1624510800, 1624511700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Temperature = c(26.6, 26.3, 26.1, 25.3, 25.2, 25.2)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
DF2 <- structure(list(timstamp = structure(c(1624485600, 1624486500, 
1624487400, 1624488300, 1624489200, 1624490100, 1624491000, 1624491900, 
1624492800, 1624493700, 1624494600, 1624495500, 1624496400, 1624497300, 
1624498200, 1624499100, 1624500000, 1624500900, 1624501800, 1624502700, 
1624503600, 1624504500, 1624505400, 1624506300, 1624507200, 1624508100, 
1624509000, 1624509900, 1624510800, 1624511700), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Temperature = c(26.6, 26.3, 
26.1, 25.3, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2, 25.1, 25, 24.8, 24.8, 24.9, 
24.8, 24.8, 24.7, 24.7, 24.7, 24.7, 24.6, 24.5, 24.3, 24.3, 24.2, 
24.1, 24.1, 24.2, 24.6, 24.8, 25.3)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example with the expected output!

Comment: When you tried the linked approach, how exactly is it not working? Complete failure, error message, unexpected result?

Comment: It is not giving the desired output, since it is not returing NA when there is no matching within the time difference range.

Comment: @TarJae, I have added an example of my datasets.

Comment: MahanadMohammed, I added the output from `dput` after doing some work on your sample data. I don't assume a timezone (it is unset). Realize that it takes a little more effort to "use" text output like you provided, since I'm inferring that your `timstamp` and `DT` columns are class `POSIXt`, yet if we just copy/paste your samples we don't get that. Please try to make it as easy for somebody to just "try" as possible, it'll help you in the long run, I believe.

Comment: @r2evans I am sorry and will do that next time. thank you very much and I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Now ... given the sample data you provided, there are no overlaps.

Comment: there are overlaps, these are only the heads of df. I will share some overlapped data shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, I'll adjust your sample data so that `DF2` contains times needed by `DF1`. My hack will be incomplete (still some `NA`s) and clearly commented, so I hope the method itself works.

Using `dplyr`'s ability to do a non-equal join:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
  mutate(timstamp = timstamp + 6*3600) %>% # hack for this answer, do not keep
  mutate(lo = timstamp - 7.5*60 + 1e-9, hi = timstamp + 7.5*60) %>%
  right_join(DF2, join_by(between(y$DT, x$lo, x$hi)))
#              timstamp Temperature                  lo                  hi                  DT     RH
# 1 2021-06-24 06:30:00        26.1 2021-06-24 06:22:30 2021-06-24 06:37:30 2021-06-24 06:33:01 73.259
# 2 2021-06-24 06:45:00        25.3 2021-06-24 06:37:30 2021-06-24 06:52:30 2021-06-24 06:48:01 66.982
# 3 2021-06-24 07:00:00        25.2 2021-06-24 06:52:30 2021-06-24 07:07:30 2021-06-24 07:03:01 66.982
# 4 2021-06-24 07:15:00        25.2 2021-06-24 07:07:30 2021-06-24 07:22:30 2021-06-24 07:18:01 66.982
# 5                <NA>          NA                <NA>                <NA> 2021-06-24 07:24:01 72.482
# 6                <NA>          NA                <NA>                <NA> 2021-06-24 07:33:01 66.982
```

Notes:

- I assumed 15-minutes centered on the time; other thoughts might use `DF2$timstamp` as the lower and `timstamp + 15` as the upper bound
- `lo` and `hi` can safely be removed later; note that `dplyr::join_by` does not allow math in its expressions, so `join_by(between(y$DT, x$timstamp - 7.5*60 + 1e-9, ...)` does not work
- not always required, I'm using `x$` and `y$` to delineate data from the LHS (`x$`) and RHS of the join/merge
- I added `1e-9` so that there is no overlap between 15-minute intervals; that is, if one row's `lo` is identical to the previous row's `hi`, and one of `DF1$DT` falls on this time, it is possible to get two instances of that row since both ends of the range are "closed"; adding `1e-9` is a hack to make the left side of the range comparison "open"

---

Sample data:

```r
DF1 <- structure(list(timstamp = structure(c(1624507200, 1624508100, 1624509000, 1624509900, 1624510800, 1624511700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Temperature = c(26.6, 26.3, 26.1, 25.3, 25.2, 25.2)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
DF2 <- structure(list(DT = structure(c(1624530781, 1624531681, 1624532581, 1624533481, 1624533841, 1624534381), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), RH = c(73.259, 66.982, 66.982, 66.982, 72.482, 66.982)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you very much. This works for me. However, I am still studying and checking it is effect on the full data.